# Post to facebook wall using c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-wall

Is it possible to do a post to someone's wall as someone else. For example Person A posts on person B's wall. Just as if `'A'` wrote directly on `B's` wall.

so far I have it working for someone posting on their own wall.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        var app = new FacebookApp(ACCESSTOKEN);
        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        args.Add("message", "Hello you");

        app.Api("/[Friend Id]/feed", args, HttpMethod.Post);
```

Honesty, I can't try it now, but I hope it's working.

Comment: And probably you have to deal with the user permissions.